# Break not in loop, unsure what to do

Tags: python

To practice python I'm doing random projects and I tried to make a spam bot that spams a google form. I've written most of it but I can't figure out how to loop the code down from a certain spot.

```
import pyautogui
import random
import webbrowser
import time
from itertools import count, repeat

list = ["Test", "test", "tesT"]

countA = input("A:")


webbrowser.open('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1YPhaNvFkncyGuCxIcJ7UhjQDeR55WX20H8cdmPxlSGU/viewform?edit_requested=true', new = 2)


while (countA<countA):
    pyautogui.moveTo(700, 360)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.click()
    item = random.choice(list)
    pyautogui.write(item)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.moveTo(700, 430)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.moveTo(700, 255)
    pyautogui.click()
    countA = countA + 1
else:
    break
```

Part I want to loop:

```
    pyautogui.moveTo(700, 360)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.click()
    item = random.choice(list)
    pyautogui.write(item)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.moveTo(700, 430)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.moveTo(700, 255)
    pyautogui.click()
    countA = countA + 1
```

I tried a while loop using break but was unsuccessful in different ways (mainly telling me break isn't in a loop). I think I managed to get the other parts done correctly (correct me if I'm wrong).
TLDR: I'm trying to get it to ask for user input on how many times it should loop and then loop the mentioned amount.

Sorry if anything is unclear.

Comment: while (countA<countA): what on earth is this supposed to do?  You do realise it's *never* true, right?

Comment: Google is the company behind Recaptcha and is *the* industry leader in anti-bot technology. If you're going to cut your teeth on spambots, a Google Form is not the place to do it. They will detect what you're doing and shut it down, without even having to involve a human in the process.

Comment: I don't understand why you need the `else` statement at all. The `while` loop will stop automatically when it's condition is no longer met. However, in this case, the condition can _never_ be met, because `countA` will _always_ equal `countA`: they're the same variable. A number can't be less than itself.

Comment: `else` executes *after* the loop (if a `break` was encountered in the loop).

Comment: Look up python's for loop and the for x in range(y) paradigm.  As it stands this code doesn't make much sense.  Your break is indeed not in a loop, but if your condition actually worked, you wouldn't need to tell while to break when the condition didn't obtain: it will do that itself.  Else with a loop doesn't do what you think (and is best left for a bit: it's handy, but not a common construction)

Comment: Also *don't* cut your teeth on spam bots.  Write something useful :p

Comment: You probably want the loop to be `for _ in range(countA):`, not a `while` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. python's `input` function returns a string, not a number of any kind. This means that the line `countA = input("A:")` sets `countA` to a value of `'3'` (a string), if the user enters `3`. You need to convert this to an integer.
   If we assume you don't care about input validation, that could look like this:

```py
countA = int(input("A:"))
```

2. You seem to be trying to use the same variable `countA` to store both how many iterations the user would like, and how many have occurred. This results in the nonsensical `while (countA<countA):`, which always fails.
   You essentially have three options for a remedy:

   - start an interation counter at 0 and increment it until it reaches the number the user specified
   - decrement the variable holding the user's input until it reaches 0
   - replace your while loop with `for _ in range(countA):`

Also, the error is correct; your `break` is not in a loop. Your `break` is in an `else` block which will be triggered if the while-loop is terminated by its condition. See [this explanation](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-while-else/)